# Grouping rows with Groupby and converting date & time of rows of start date-time and end date- time columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset looking like this:

[image: Dataset]

```html
Blast Hole East Coordinate North Coordinate Collar Theoritical Depth Tag Detector ID Date and Time Detection_Location Detection Date & Time
64 16745.42 107390.32 2634.45 15.95 385656531 23-08-2018 2:39:34 PM CV23 2018-09-08 14:18:17
61 16773.48 107382.6 2634.68 16.18 385760755 23-08-2018 2:38:32 PM CV23 2018-09-08 14:24:19
63 16755.07 107387.68 2634.58 16.08 385262370 23-08-2018 2:39:30 PM CV23 2018-09-08 14:12:42
105 16764.83 107347.67 2634.74 16.24 385742468 23-08-2018 2:41:29 PM CV22 2018-09-06 20:02:46
100 16752.74 107360.32 2634.33 15.83 385112050 23-08-2018 2:41:08 PM CV22 2018-09-06 20:15:42
99 16743.1 107362.96 2634.36 15.86 385087366 23-08-2018 2:41:05 PM CV22 2018-09-06 20:49:21
35 16747.75 107417.68 2635.9 17.4 385453358 23-08-2018 2:36:09 PM CV22 2018-09-23 05:47:44
5 16757.27 107452.4 2636 17.5 385662254 23-08-2018 2:35:03 PM CV22 2018-09-23 05:01:12
19 16770.89 107420.83 2634.81 16.31 385826979 23-08-2018 2:35:50 PM CV22 2018-09-23 05:52:54
```

I intended to group all the rows having 3 detections at one place ( in column Detection_location) in one hour.
I used the following code for grouping the rows falling in one hour per 3 detection:

```
df2 = df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection Date & Time', freq = 'H'), 
      df1.Detection_Location]).size().reset_index(name = 'Tags')
```

This code gave me a result like this:
[image: Primary result]

I would rather like to have result in which each rows have start time when the first detection was there in that hour and when the last detection was seen and thus i would like to have a result like this:

[image: Final output]

```html
This is the required output:

Detection Date & Time - Start  Detection Date & Time - End Detection_Location Tags
2018-09-06 20:02:46 2018-09-06 20:49:21 CV22 3
2018-09-08 14:12:42 2018-09-08 14:24:19 CV23 3
2018-09-23 05:01:12 2018-09-23 05:47:44 CV22 3
```

Can anyone suggest what else should i add in my group-by function to get this result.

Thanks

Comment: Is this dataset in a database or in memory?

Comment: @IainShelvington - Hi, its in memory.

Comment: Can you paste snippet of your data & expected output (you can paste them in HTML snippets)? This helps us run it at our end to find the right solution.

Comment: @mohanys - i have added snippets of the requested parts of question as HTML snippets. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for you. Inside the aggregate function, you can pass all the values that you want to capture.

```
df2 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection Date & Time', freq = 'H'),df.Detection_Location],sort=False)['Detection Date & Time']
   .agg(['first','last','size'])).reset_index().rename(columns={"first": "Detection Date & Time - Start", "last": "Detection Date & Time - End", "size": "Tags"})
```

Comment: Hi @mohanys - This works fine in the way that it picks the first and the last value but as you see in the data set that the data set is not aligned as ascending or descending date and time but rather on bunches of detection based on which location they were detected so its picking up wrong values. If we can somehow sort the date and time without disturbing the group of 3 within an hour concept, this code will perfectly pick the right values. Many thanks

Comment: Use `sort=False` within the `groupby`. Code updated in the answer.

Comment: Hi @mohanys - tried putting sort = False in groupby as well but still picking up wrong values. I tried doing : df1 = df1.sort_values(by =['Detection Date & Time'])......a sorting of dataframe by date & time and the results are coming to be correct. I fear it does not have any contraindications. Need to test multiple  test cases to ensure that but so far so good. Thanks lot. Closing this question :)

Comment: For me when i use `sort=False` within the `groupby` (as in my code). I am getting unsorted results (matching the order of the data). Anyway, good luck.

Comment: yes you are right. We get matching the order of the data, its just that the data was not in order of datetime. So i sorted it first , and now your code working perfect now. thanks :)