# Combining Groupby function codes, with and without grouper

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have written these two groupby functions on my data sets, the first one grouped my data and seperated datetime for the data as start datetime, end date time.

This is the dataset:

```html
Blast Hole East Coordinate North Coordinate Collar Theoritical Depth Tag Detector ID Date and Time Detection_Location Detection Date & Time
64 16745.42 107390.32 2634.45 15.95 385656531 23-08-2018 2:39:34 PM CV23 2018-09-08 14:18:17
61 16773.48 107382.6 2634.68 16.18 385760755 23-08-2018 2:38:32 PM CV23 2018-09-08 14:24:19
63 16755.07 107387.68 2634.58 16.08 385262370 23-08-2018 2:39:30 PM CV23 2018-09-08 14:12:42
105 16764.83 107347.67 2634.74 16.24 385742468 23-08-2018 2:41:29 PM CV22 2018-09-06 20:02:46
100 16752.74 107360.32 2634.33 15.83 385112050 23-08-2018 2:41:08 PM CV22 2018-09-06 20:15:42
99 16743.1 107362.96 2634.36 15.86 385087366 23-08-2018 2:41:05 PM CV22 2018-09-06 20:49:21
35 16747.75 107417.68 2635.9 17.4 385453358 23-08-2018 2:36:09 PM CV22 2018-09-23 05:47:44
5 16757.27 107452.4 2636 17.5 385662254 23-08-2018 2:35:03 PM CV22 2018-09-23 05:01:12
19 16770.89 107420.83 2634.81 16.31 385826979 23-08-2018 2:35:50 PM CV22 2018-09-23 05:52:54
```

The second part helped me keeping all the columns in the grouped dataframe as before seperated by comma.

I am though facing problem in how to combine these two codes to form a single code and perform action:

```py
df2 = (df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection Date & Time', freq = 'H'),df.Detection_Location])
      ['Detection Date & Time'].agg(['first','last','size'])).reset_index()
```

```py
df2 = df1.groupby("Detection date & Hour").agg({
        'Blast Hole': lambda x: ','.join([str(n) for n in x]),
        'East Coordinate': lambda x: ','.join([str(n) for n in x]),
        'North Coordinate': lambda x: ','.join([str(n) for n in x]),
        'Tag Detector ID': lambda x: ','.join([str(n) for n in x]),
        'Detection_Location': lambda x: min(x),
        'Detection Date & Time' : lambda x: len(x)}).reset_index().rename(columns = {'Detection Date & Time' : 'Tags'})
```

This is the desired result:

```html
Detection_Location_ first last size Blast Hole East Coordinate North Coordinate Tag Detector ID
CV22 2018-09-06 20:02:46 2018-09-06 20:49:21 3 105,100,99 16764.83,16752.74,16743.1 107347.67,107360.32,107362.96 385742468,385112050,385087366
CV23 2018-09-08 14:12:42 2018-09-08 14:24:19 3 64,61,63 16745.42,16773.48,16755.07 107390.32,107382.6,107387.68 385656531,385760755,385262370
CV22 2018-09-23 05:01:12 2018-09-23 05:52:54 3 35,5,19 16747.75,16757.27,16770.89 107417.68,107452.4,107420.83 385453358,385662254,385826979
```

[image: result]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is if need different values in `groupby` - first `df21` with `Grouper` and second with only `Grouper`:

```
df1['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date and Time'])
df1['Detection Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Detection Date & Time'])


df21 = (df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection Date & Time', freq = 'H'),
                     df1.Detection_Location])
      ['Detection Date & Time'].agg(['first','last','size']))
#print (df21)


f = lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))
df22=(df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection Date & Time', freq = 'H')).agg({
        'Blast Hole': f,
        'East Coordinate': f,
        'North Coordinate': f,
        'Tag Detector ID': f,
        'Detection_Location': 'min',
        'Detection Date & Time' : 'size'})
        .dropna()
        .rename(columns = {'Detection Date & Time' : 'Tags'})
        .set_index('Detection_Location', append=True))

#print (df22)
```

---

```
df = pd.merge(df21, df22, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()
print (df)
  Detection Date & Time Detection_Location               first  \
0   2018-09-06 20:00:00               CV22 2018-09-06 20:02:46   
1   2018-09-08 14:00:00               CV23 2018-09-08 14:18:17   
2   2018-09-23 05:00:00               CV22 2018-09-23 05:47:44   

                 last  size  Blast Hole             East Coordinate  \
0 2018-09-06 20:49:21     3  105,100,99   16764.83,16752.74,16743.1   
1 2018-09-08 14:12:42     3    63,64,61  16755.07,16745.42,16773.48   
2 2018-09-23 05:52:54     3     5,35,19  16757.27,16747.75,16770.89   

                North Coordinate                Tag Detector ID  Tags  
0  107347.67,107360.32,107362.96  385742468,385112050,385087366     3  
1   107387.68,107390.32,107382.6  385262370,385656531,385760755     3  
2   107452.4,107417.68,107420.83  385662254,385453358,385826979     3
```

EDIT:

If need grouping by `Grouper` and column together:

```
df1['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date and Time'])
df1['Detection Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Detection Date & Time'])


f = lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))
df2=(df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Detection Date & Time',freq='H'),
                 df1.Detection_Location]).agg({
        'Blast Hole': f,
        'East Coordinate': f,
        'North Coordinate': f,
        'Tag Detector ID': f,
        'Detection Date & Time' : ['first','last','size']})
               .reset_index()
               .rename(columns = {'Detection Date & Time' : '', '<lambda>':''}))

df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'' : 'Detection Date & Time'})
```

---

```
print (df2)
  Detection Date & Time Detection_Location  Blast Hole  \
0   2018-09-06 20:00:00               CV22  105,100,99   
1   2018-09-08 14:00:00               CV23    64,61,63   
2   2018-09-23 05:00:00               CV22     35,5,19   

              East Coordinate               North Coordinate  \
0   16764.83,16752.74,16743.1  107347.67,107360.32,107362.96   
1  16745.42,16773.48,16755.07   107390.32,107382.6,107387.68   
2  16747.75,16757.27,16770.89   107417.68,107452.4,107420.83   

                 Tag Detector ID               first                last  size  
0  385742468,385112050,385087366 2018-09-06 20:02:46 2018-09-06 20:49:21     3  
1  385656531,385760755,385262370 2018-09-08 14:18:17 2018-09-08 14:12:42     3  
2  385453358,385662254,385826979 2018-09-23 05:47:44 2018-09-23 05:52:54     3
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael - This gives me this error : columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Detection_Location'], dtype='object')

Comment: I think few columns over lap and i need to cut few lines of code. Would try. Thanks

Comment: @ShrutiGaur - Try `df2 = df21.join(df22, lsuffix='_')`

Comment: @jexrael - df22 showing up blank after the joining in df2

Comment: @ShrutiGaur - Can you create some sample data - 4-5 rows?

Comment: @zsh_18 - Can you test now?

Comment: the other columns are not producing values in list separated by comma with this code.

Comment: @zsh_18 - Added second solution (idea like ansother anwer - grouping by Grouper and column `Detection_Location`) in both groupings joined together.

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks ton !

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you (i know how your data looks like from your earlier question)
You can aggregate all the values into a list with just `agg(list)`

```
df3=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection_Date&Time', freq = 'H'),df.Detection_Location], sort=False).agg(list).reset_index()
```

Then you merge the other one (from your other question to the result, df2 here) as below

```
df2 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection_Date&Time', freq = 'H'),df.Detection_Location], sort=False)['Detection_Date&Time']
   .agg(['first','last','size'])).reset_index()

df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, on=['Detection_Date&Time','Detection_Location'])
```

The output obtained is as below

```
Detection_Date&Time     Detection_Location  first   last    size    Blast_Hole  East_Coordinate     North_Coordinate    Collar  Theoritical_Depth   Tag_Detector_ID     Date_and_Time
0   2018-09-08 14:00:00     CV23    2018-09-08 14:18:00     2018-09-08 14:12:00     3   [64, 61, 63]    [16745.42, 16773.48, 16755.07]  [107390.32, 107382.6, 107387.68]    [2634.45, 2634.68, 2634.58]     [15.95, 16.18, 16.08]   [385656531, 385760755, 385262370]   [23-08-2018 2:39:34 PM, 23-08-2018 2:38:32 PM,...
1   2018-09-06 20:00:00     CV22    2018-09-06 20:02:00     2018-09-06 20:49:00     3   [105, 100, 99]  [16764.83, 16752.74, 16743.1]   [107347.67, 107360.32, 107362.96]   [2634.74, 2634.33, 2634.36]     [16.24, 15.83, 15.86]   [385742468, 385112050, 385087366]   [23-08-2018 2:41:29 PM, 23-08-2018 2:41:08 PM,...
2   2018-09-23 05:00:00     CV22    2018-09-23 05:47:00     2018-09-23 05:52:00     3   [35, 5, 19]     [16747.75, 16757.27, 16770.89]  [107417.68, 107452.4, 107420.83]    [2635.9, 2636.0, 2634.81]   [17.4, 17.5, 16.31]     [385453358, 385662254, 385826979]   [23-08-2018 2:36:09 PM, 23-08-2018 2:35:03 PM,...
```

Comment: in both the dataframe 'Detection_Date&Time' & 'Detection_Location' are same. It is working for me.

Comment: please see the earlier question. there, there are pictures of what was expected. that y i why i mentioned that i know the data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549303/grouping-rows-with-groupby-and-converting-date-time-of-rows-of-start-date-time/57550312?noredirect=1#comment101563774_57550312

Comment: @mohanys - thanks. Though when we create the first dataframe df3 - the column detection_location already exist and when we pass (list) to aggregate function it gives the following error : cannot insert Detection_Location, already exists

Comment: @jezrael - yes the data and expected outcome for this question is in this question only. you are right

Comment: @mohanys - the output you are showing is perfect, i will try the code again.Thanks

Comment: @zsh_18 use both 'Detection_Date&Time' & 'Detection_Location' in `groupby`. then you will have this error.

Comment: @mohanys - Don't know why, still getting the same error - cannot insert Detection_Location, already exists

Comment: It works for me just fine, i am not sure why you are getting error. Please the code line by line. If you paste the entire code here, i will try to check it as well.